# BDR error :ERROR: could not open extension control file

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-bdr

BDR error :
when making changes to the postgresql.conf for 
shared_preload_libraries = ’pglogical,bdr’

``FATAL:  could not access file "pglogical": No such file or directory```

also cannot make extension `postgres=# create extension BDR;
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/bdr.control": No such file or directory` Its Postgresql 10 and BDR3

Comment: So how did you install the BDR PostgreSQL extension on your system? And what system it is? Same for `pglogical`.  There is not only configuration to change, you have the software to install..